# If statement is not evaluating as True even when condition is met

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to learn how to do user input validation and build off this post
[How to return a specific point after an error in 'while' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961271/how-to-return-a-specific-point-after-an-error-in-while-loop)

I believe the issue is when current_answer is evaluated against the answer list. Regardless of what I enter for a number, the 'else' statement kicks in.

```
def input_validator(question, answers):
    while True:
        current_answer = input(question)
        if current_answer in answers:
            print('Success')
            break
        print ('Failure')
    return current_answer

inputQuarter = input_validator('What quarter is being processed (1,2,3,4)?: ', [1,2,3,4] )
```

I'm assuming the problem lies with something I don't understand about breaking the for loop because the if/else statement seems to work fine outside of the loop.

Comment: Please fix your indenting.

Comment: What is your intended output, and what are the current results?

Comment: `input()` returns a string, `answers` contains numbers. So either convert the input to a number, or change `answers` to a list of strings.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the loop. The `if` statement should not work outside it.

Comment: What is being returned and what is intended to be returned from the function.

Comment: Are you comparing a string with an integer? Try converting all to string before comparing.

Comment: @JohnMee Isn't that what I said?

Comment: Sorry; at first I thought your comment was directed at me, and realized it's not.

Comment: If you ever think that an `if` statement is not working, it's almost surely because your condition is not written correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the function here:

```
inputQuarter = input_validator('What quarter is being processed (1,2,3,4)?: ', [1,2,3,4] )
```

Then the `answers` going to hold a `list` with the values: `[1,2,3,4]`, that is 4 integers.
When you call the function `input()` like this:

```
current_answer = input(question)
```

**No matter** what is the input the user gave you, it will never be evaluated to `True` here:

```
if current_answer in answers:
```

Because `answers` hold list of integers and `input()` returns a `string`. Therefore `current_answer` is a string.

You can solve this in 2 ways:

1. Make the `list` as `list` of strings:

```
inputQuarter = input_validator('What quarter is being processed (1,2,3,4)?: ', ["1","2","3","4"] )
```

2. Make the `current_answer` to an integer:

```
current_answer = int(input(question))
```

I personally prefer the first, because it will work for more complicated answers as well (Just know that it will be case sensitive!).